# Do Equatable need to be immutable

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, hash, equatable

Is there real case scenarios of not following immutable leading to wrong hash outcome?

I've made a test case to test the non-immutable class and was expecting it to have an error. In reality we do not have any problems with that and HashSet actually works fine here.

Can you show us a simple real case scenario where not following immutable will lead to wrong hashcode value

```
import 'dart:collection';

import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class _EquatableTest extends Equatable {
  final HashSet values;

  const _EquatableTest({required this.values});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [values];

  _EquatableTest copyWith({
    HashSet? values,
  }) {
    return _EquatableTest(
      values: values ?? this.values,
    );
  }
}

class _EquatableTestNonImmutable extends Equatable {
  HashSet values;

  _EquatableTestNonImmutable({required this.values});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [values];
}

class _AdditionalValue extends Equatable {
  HashSet<String> letters;

  _AdditionalValue({required this.letters});

  void add(String letter) {
    letters.add(letter);
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [letters];
}

void main() {
test('NonImmutable created same with _AdditionalValue value', () {
    _EquatableTest equatableImmune1;
    _EquatableTest equatableImmune2;

    equatableImmune1 = _EquatableTest(values: HashSet<_AdditionalValue>());
    equatableImmune2 = _EquatableTest(values: HashSet<_AdditionalValue>());

    equatableImmune1.values.add(_AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet.from(['a', 'b'])));
    equatableImmune1.values.add(_AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet.from(['c', 'd'])));

    equatableImmune2.values.add(_AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet.from(['a', 'b'])));
    equatableImmune2.values.add(_AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet.from(['c', 'd'])));

    expect(equatableImmune1, equatableImmune2);
  });

  test('NonImmutable changed same with _AdditionalValue value', () {
    _EquatableTest equatableImmune1;
    _EquatableTest equatableImmune2;

    equatableImmune1 = _EquatableTest(values: HashSet<_AdditionalValue>());
    equatableImmune2 = _EquatableTest(values: HashSet<_AdditionalValue>());

    _AdditionalValue value1 = _AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet<String>());
    _AdditionalValue value2 = _AdditionalValue(letters: HashSet<String>());

    value1.add('a');
    value2.add('a');

    equatableImmune1.values.add(value1);
    equatableImmune2.values.add(value2);

    expect(equatableImmune1, equatableImmune2);

    if (equatableImmune1.values.first.runtimeType == _AdditionalValue &&
        equatableImmune2.values.first.runtimeType == _AdditionalValue) {
      equatableImmune1.values.first.add('b');
      equatableImmune2.values.first.add('b');
    }

    expect(equatableImmune1, equatableImmune2);
    expect(equatableImmune1.hashCode, equatableImmune2.hashCode);
  });
}
```

Comment: two objects that are identical() are expected to have the same unchanging hashCode, and there are definitely circumstances where violating that will give you all sorts of grief.  Since mutating your object will change the hashCode, you'll be in trouble.  Maybe not for the testcases you have, but somewhere...

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yep.. I'm trying to find that "somewhere"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there real case scenarios of not following immutable leading to wrong hash outcome?

A trivial example:

```dart
class Mutable {
  int x;

  Mutable(this.x);

  @override
  bool operator==(Object other) => other is Mutable && x == other.x;

  @override
  int get hashCode => x.hashCode;
}

void main() {
  var m = Mutable(0);

  var set = {m};
  print(set.contains(Mutable(0))); // Prints: true

  m.x = 1;
  print(set.contains(Mutable(1))); // Prints: false

  print(set.contains(set.first)); // Prints: false
}
```

So now the `Set` is in an inconsistent state where it doesn't even think it contains its only element.

Comment: https://dartpad.dev/5fdaad2901e61469f4663811c3215b61

can you explain why 2 is false? and why you added it then

Comment: I mean "second". The dartpad links are broken rn, so I'll send you gist directly https://gist.github.com/Nikzed/5fdaad2901e61469f4663811c3215b61

Comment: @NikitaShadkov In my example, `set.contains(set.first)` doesn't work because the `Set` is in an internally inconsistent state: it has an element whose current `hashCode` doesn't match the value that it originally had when it was added to the `Set`, so all lookups on that element will fail.

Comment: If you're asking why `setI.contains(const Immutable(1))` is `false` in your gist, then that doesn't work because `setI` contains only an `Immutable(0)` element. `i = i.copyWith(x: 1)`does not mutate any objects; it creates a new object and assigns that to the local variable `i`.  That new object is not part of `setI`.